# Handedness — Observational study vs. Experiment

Tags: experiment-design, observational-study

Let's say your goal is to determine whether left handed people are more coordinated with their right hands than right handed people are with their left.

You gather up 20 left-handed people and 20 right-handed people, have each one throw a ball into a basket with both their dominant and non-dominant hands, and then compare the distribution of the ratio of makes with non-dominant vs. dominant between both groups.

Would this be considered as an experiment or an observational study?

---

I am leaning towards it being a prospective observational study since it lacks the notable characteristics of an experiment, such as random assignment — you cannot randomly assign handedness.

On the other hand (no pun intended), since you have two groups and are comparing outcomes between them, could this in a sense be a matched experiment?

I also found [this](http://deutsch.ucsd.edu/pdf/Ch-Handedness-1980.pdf) experiment dealing with handedness vs. tonal pitch memory that seems to have a similar setup where they compare one statistic across two groups:

> This experiment employed 74 right-handers and 30 left-handers... The right-handers produced an average error rate of 41.5% and the left-handers a rate
>   of 36.5%.

which seems similar to this setup, substituting error rates for ratio of success with non-dominant vs dominant.

Comment: You are right, it is observational.  The explanatory variable (handedness) was not assigned randomly to subjects.

Comment: @AlaskaRon But let's say you randomly assigned the starting throwing hand for each subject (i.e., if you get heads then the subject does the first 10 throws with his dominant hand and the remaining 10 with the non-dominant and vice-versa if tails). Then couldn't you consider this as a matched experiment?

Comment: Then, yes, it would be an experiment.  But in this case the "treatment" that is being tested is:  Does throwing with the dominant hand first have a different effect than throwing with the non-dominant hand first.  In other words, you are testing the treatments "dominant first, than non dominant" vs "non dominant followed by dominant".  You aren't testing anything about right vs left hands.  Any inference about right handed people vs left handed people would be an observational study that was a side effect of your experiment.

Comment: @AlaskaRon Ah that makes sense. However, the [linked](http://deutsch.ucsd.edu/pdf/Ch-Handedness-1980.pdf) article describes a similar setup of relating handedness vs. a statistic (tonal pitch memory) as an experiment. Why is this considered an experiment whereas my scenario is an observational study?

Comment: I'm guessing that they are using 'experiment' in a loose sense.  What they did was certainly what is called in most statistics courses an observational study, but if they might define an experiment to be a study where you interact with the subjects to get your measurement.  Then you would have to make a distinction between an experiment vs a randomized experiment.